# Different way to store view & data except activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, lifecycle

I want to display content and view in my android application, I have a menu inflater, when I click on one of the options I need to display a regular form - I did it till now with an activity, I displayed it when ever somebody clicked on of the option in my menu. The problem is that when I am installing my application on my device I get different icons (One for my main app and another one for my second activity - Is there any way to disable the second activity icon or display content in another way that isn't using activity?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Android creates Launcher icons for all the activities which have their category defined as "LAUNCHER".

In your AndroidManifest.xml file remove the following line for the second activity

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

or replace it with

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```